# How to get resultset data in grails

Tags: java, grails, resultset

Below is my query:

```
def getdata1 = sql.rows("select student_id,school_grade_class_id from class_assign")
```

How do I get `student_id` from `getdata1`?

**UPDATE:**

```
def getdata1 = sql.rows("select student_id,school_grade_class_id from class_assign")


def getdata2 = sql.rows("select class_id,class_name,school_grade_id from class_rel where school_grade_class_id=**x**")
```

I should replace x to resultset v`alue of school_grade_class_id` from `getdata1`. 
What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
getdata1.each{
    println it.student_id
}
```

Or

```
sql.eachRow("select student_id,school_grade_class_id from class_assign", {
   println it.student_id
})
```

Comment: thx for the reply.How can i give the value to next query chck UPDATE